# Exclude categories from the_category();

Tags: query

```
function the_category_filter($thelist,$separator=' ') {
    if(!defined('WP_ADMIN')) {
        //list the category names to exclude
        $exclude = array('Something','Something Else','Blah','YAY');
        $cats = explode($separator,$thelist);
        $newlist = array();
        foreach($cats as $cat) {
            $catname = trim(strip_tags($cat));
            if(!in_array($catname,$exclude))
                $newlist[] = $cat;
        }
        return implode($separator,$newlist);
    } else
        return $thelist;
}
add_filter('the_category','the_category_filter',10,2);
```

I am using that code, to get the_category(); to exclude some categories. But it ain't working, as it is supposed to...

Answer (score 7):

Try using the filter `get_the_categories` and replace every occurrence of `the_category` by `echo get_the_category()` (just to be sure !)

This is what I cooked:

```
<?php
add_filter('get_the_categories', 'exc_cat');

function exc_cat($cats) {
        //not on admin pages
        if(!is_admin()){
            $exc = array('lipsum', 'dolor');
            foreach ($cats as $i=>$cat){
                if(in_array($cat->name, $exc)){
                   unset($cats[$i]); 
                }
            }
        }
    return $cats;
}
?>
```

Try my code and let me know if it does your job.

Comment: The error is the following:

syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

at line:1

Comment: Check my modified answer and code... I've tested it, it works.

Comment: Hm, check this out... check out the output... It prints the array :O

http://stu.gr/%CF%80%CF%81%CF%8E%CF%84%CE%BF-%CF%80%CE%BF%CF%83%CF%84-%CE%B3%CE%B9%CE%B1-%CF%84%CE%BF-stu-gr/

Comment: Because, I left the `print_r` statements so that you could see the arrays! No problem, comment them out as I've updated my answer code. Check it now.

Comment: Hey thanks for the effort. Check it now also, it just outputs the world array! :D

Comment: Strange... I checked my code locally with 3 different themes, it works neat. Try copying the new code from my answer, I've removed all the unnecessary `print_r` statements.

Answer (score 3):

This will work:

Put the following in your functions.php file:

```
function exclude_post_categories($excl='', $spacer=' '){
   $categories = get_the_category($post->ID);
      if(!empty($categories)){
        $exclude=$excl;
        $exclude = explode(",", $exclude);
        $thecount = count(get_the_category()) - count($exclude);
        foreach ($categories as $cat) {
            $html = '';
            if(!in_array($cat->cat_ID, $exclude)) {
                $html .= '<a href="' . get_category_link($cat->cat_ID) . '" ';
                $html .= 'title="' . $cat->cat_name . '">' . $cat->cat_name . '</a>';
                if($thecount>1){
                    $html .= $spacer;
                }
            $thecount--;
            echo $html;
            }
          }
      }
}
```

and then call the function with:

```
<?php exclude_post_categories('1,5', ', '); ?>
```

where 1 or 5 are the category IDs you want to exclude.

Code courtesy of http://wordpress.org/support/topic/the_category-exclude-categories

Comment: +1 This one is interesting because it can be both ways, with or without exclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Enter this handy function from the WordPress support forums — just add it to your theme’s functions.php file:

```
function the_category_filter($thelist,$separator=' ') {
     // list the IDs of the categories to exclude
     $exclude = array(366);
     // create an empty array
     $exclude2 = array();

     // loop through the excluded IDs and get their actual names
     foreach($exclude as $c) {
          // store the names in the second array
          $exclude2[] = get_cat_name($c);
     }

     // get the list of categories for the current post     
     $cats = explode($separator,$thelist);
     // create another empty array      
     $newlist = array();

     foreach($cats as $cat) {
          // remove the tags from each category
          $catname = trim(strip_tags($cat));

          // check against the excluded categories
          if(!in_array($catname,$exclude2))

          // if not in that list, add to the new array
          $newlist[] = $cat;
     }
     // return the new, shortened list
     return implode($separator,$newlist);
}

// add the filter to 'the_category' tag
add_filter('the_category','the_category_filter', 10, 2);
```

Initially, I did have some issues with this function; after some tinkering around, I realized I needed a separator declared in the_category() tag, like a comma, dash, etc. In this case, I was using just a space — `the_category(' ')` — which wasn’t working, but swapping it out for a non-breaking space did the trick: `the_category('&nbsp;').`

Credit: http://www.stemlegal.com/greenhouse/2012/excluding-categories-from-the-category-tag-in-wordpres/

Answer (score -1):

I have been looking for a solution for something like this and I make some modifications to some code posted in various topics and I get this..

```
<?php foreach((get_the_category()) as $cat) {
if (($cat->cat_ID=='#')) 
echo $cat->cat_name;
} ?>
```

where # = your cat ID.
I hope it works for you.

Comment: This is not a proper answer. Please add a proper explanation to what your code does and how it works

Comment: It displays particular category related to a post..